# upload image with data to server Titanium

Tags: http, titanium

i have some data i need to upload it to the server with an image using

```
multipart/form-data
```

but i getting request time out  this is my data

```
  var data={
       property_name:p_n_txt.value,
       friendly_name:f_txt.value,
       property_type:clicked,
       size:space_Slider.getValue(),
       price:price_Slider.getValue(),
       number_of_bedrooms:bedrooms_Slider.getValue(),
       number_of_bathrooms:bathrooms_Slider.getValue(),
       number_of_parkings:p_space_Slider.getValue(),
       location:a_txt.value,
       features:13,
       payment_method:4,
       image1_name:"image0.png",
       image1:Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.tempDirectory,Ti.App.Properties.getString("filename")),

   };
```

and the httpclient is

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function() {
    var myData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(this.responseText);


    },
    // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
    onerror : function(e) {
    Ti.API.debug(e.error);
    console.log(this.status);
    console.log(e.error);

    },
    timeout : 20000
    });

    xhr.open('POST','http://url/');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
     // xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");

    xhr.send(data);


});
```

here is should form data not a json so there is no need to add `json.stringify`

but i have 4 cases i tried with them

first :with stringify i got HTTP 415 if i added contentType "image/png"
and HTTP 500 if i didn't added
second without stringify when i add  added contentType "image/png" i got request time out
and when i didn't add it i get HTTP 413
any idea on how to accomplish this cause i found many question about it but no one was helpful for me
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try with encoding your image as base64encoded and pass it on and at the server end just decode it and you would be go enough to proceed.

```
Ti.Utils.base64encode(image.toBlob()).toString();
```

This can be sent to server and no headers would be required to sent.